# Infopath CodeBehind Assembly Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, infopath, vsta

I am using Infopath 2010 + VS2010 + Sharepoint 2010.(VSTA for infopath codebehind is Visual C# 2005).

My problem is that i have used codebehind for my infopath form but my form doesnt open in sharepoint 2010 giving an error like

> "The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)".

I have placed the codebehind assembly in GAC, restarted IIS, provided wrkTaskIp.aspx page with the assembly info like

```
"<%@ Assembly Name="LifelongblogSubmit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral PublicKeyToken=0e5f139fbc285b37"%>",
```

but still my error is on.

Anyone please suggest me what should i do to get rid off this.

Comment: I have found the solution and its working perfectly. m gonna tell you how i have done. 1)Wrote code behind(Doesn't matter where its saved.You only need the dll). 2)Publish the form as administrator approved then upload as site content type. 3)place your code behind's dll ain the folder where your infopath form is located after deployment. And your form gonna work i hope so. Still if anyone found problems just as a question here

Answer (score 0):

Through the search results in google with HRESULT code of yours; there seems to be a assembly name issue there.

References: [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/95832/assembly-load-returns-unknown-error-hresult-0x80131047) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvb/thread/02be3d7e-cff5-47a7-a00a-1c5ebfcb47a7)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for ur responce....
These were not helpful for me as i have already tried them.
Have anyone worked on infopath with code behind.Because i want to know that if i have to include feature, reference etc in my project solution or not?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see where your code is being saved.  Form Options --> Programming.  If you are saving your code to a network drive and that drive is not available, then your code will not work since InfoPath "doesn't see" the programming location.

1. Copy the existing code
2. Go to Form Options --> Programming and click 'Remove Code'
3. Browse for a location on your C:\
4. Edit what ever object's form code
5. Paste existing code

Comment: I have found the solution and its working perfectly.
m gonna tell you how i have done.
1)Wrote code behind(Doesn't matter where its saved.You only need the dll).
2)Publish the form as administrator approved then upload as site content type.
3)place your code behind's dll ain the folder where your infopath form is located after deployment.
And your form gonna work i hope so.
Still if anyone found problems just as a question here